# Matlab Calculating bond prices with varying discount rates

Tags: finance, quantitative-finance

I am absolute new programmer and I'm completely stuck on one problem in Matlab.

We need to calculate prices of bonds with varying discount rates. Price of a bond is given by the sum of cashflows (given) divided by a discount factor for the given year.

[image]

If you have only one rate it's a fairly simple function. However, when there is a vector of rates it gets complicated because of the matrices sizes, thus you need to use a for loop. My code looked like this:

```
function c = bond_price(DF, T, R)

c = sum(DF./(1+R).^T);
end

DF1 = [62.5 62.5 62.5 62.5 62.5 62.5 62.5]; %this is given
T1 = (1:7);                                 %also given
R1 = (0 : 0.01 : 0.10);                     %also given
prices = zeros(1, length(R1);
for k = 1 : length(R1)
    prices(k) = prices + vec_sum(DF1, T1, R1(k));
end
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"... why this doesn't work?"*

The first why ( repairable here ):

```
  syntax error

>>> prices = zeros(1, length(R1);
                                ^
```

The second why ( undecidable here ):

```
function c = bond_price( DF, T, R )
         c = sum( DF./( 1 + R ).^T );
end

DF1 = [62.5 62.5 62.5 62.5 62.5 62.5 62.5]; %% this is given
T1  = (1:7);                                %%    also given
R1  = (0 : 0.01 : 0.10);                    %%    also given
                                            %% ---------------------------------<as-was>-state
                                            %%  syntax error
                                            %%
                                            %% >>> prices = zeros(1, length(R1);
                                            %%                                 ^
prices = zeros( 1, length( R1 ) );

for k = 1 : length( R1 )
    prices(k) = prices + vec_sum( DF1, T1, R1(k) );
end
                                            %% --------------------------------<syntax-repaired>-state
                                            %% error: 'vec_sum' undefined near line 16 column 26
                                            %%
```

Feel free to repair your code and [re-test](https://tio.run/##rVLbasJAFHzfr5iXYoImzQq1oDZP4geEvJUq2@Sowbgruxt7@fl0E1Na2lJJ6bC5wJmZc9g5KrPiRHW9qWRmCyWR4Q6PSubroy4y8rBYjpCOkMBneEfDMdWhKYbXHjiGTT1cpfBnjGTO2GLJHed@Mg5v8OvrYYarK9hdYeDOtjiRZCmHE3t8euvPcAFO7CBKozpxchZHmCIKI95@ePSz0TcxesCJg0uYCxM8CRMHxgpLfe1hXqQVzyCtle4p7tsrjmO0iRt3e6@klfH4CCXJrd15CXe59h3@AlbsSzt89IML0W92iW2Uxt5Rmhw/F9tpzgbe3neEzmyIE2XrbjedYeqehDeUbjP/OeH5OaJA01EUmvI/Jt0mPMWgG36ASua0KSTlkCQ0SvcLPkGmyuogMZ70bVDXbw) the problem, as the `vec_sum()` ought be somewhere "near" in your source code, ought be not?